# var = [[0]*5]*5 Help understanding python lists?

Tags: python, coding-style

I came across a piece of python list decclaration. I am bit confused about the behavior of it.
Can somone please explain this. Appreciate your help.

```
    >>> v  = [[0]*2]*2
    >>> v
    [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    >>> v[1][1] = 23
    >>> v
    [[0, 23], [0, 23]]
    >>> v[1][1] = 44
    >>> v
    [[0, 44], [0, 44]]
    >>>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*` operator for lists repeats their contents, as you can clearly see in the output.

However, it does not copy elements, it just copies object references. So in this case, both `[0,0 ]`s have the same underlying list object, which should explain the phenomenon.

To verify this, try `v[0] = [0,44]` to assign a new (and thus independent!) list object to the first element of the master list; then re-try changing `v[1][1]`. This time only one entry will change in the output.

Comment: that explains it , so how can it fixed ?

Comment: For example, `[[0]*2 for n in range(M)]` generates a list with m independent elements `[0,0]`.

Comment: @vinay: by using something like `v = [[0]*2 for i in range(0,2)]`

Comment: can you explain the above syntax . not quit clear yet. [[0]*2 for n in range(M)]

Comment: Check out list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

v is simply a list of lists.

the * thing first line mean "repeat 2 times 0 in my list]. So each nest list is of size 2 and contain zeros.

Then you simply set values to certain cells of your list of lists :)